# Pipelining cut sort uniq

Tags: linux, sorting, pipeline, cut, uniq

Trying to get a certain field from a sam file, sort it and then find the number of unique numbers in the file. I have been trying:

```
cut -f 2 practice.sam > field2.txt | sort -o field2.txt sortedfield2.txt |  
uniq -c sortedfield2.txt
```

The cut is working to pull out the numbers from field two, however when trying to sort the numbers into a new file or the same file I am just getting a blank. I have tried breaking the pipeline into sections but still getting the same error. I am meant to use those three functions to achieve the output count.

Comment: Ah ok. We were taught that the pipeline was iterative; when it finished with one part it would move on to the next. Thanks for that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you were taught, but I think you may simply have missed some points (what would iterative even mean in a pipeline? what is "the pipeline"?). Not too worry, that can all be cleared up and learned, but you may want to mull shell pipes and redirects over a while.

Comment: Related (nearly duplicate, though the answer would in the question itself): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584727/using-linux-cut-sort-and-uniq?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609322/sorting-and-counting-method-faster-then-cat-file-sort-uniq-c?rq=1 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
cut -f 2 practice.sam | sort -o | uniq -c
```

---

In your original code, you're redirecting the output of `cut` to `field2.txt` and at the same time, trying to pipe the output into `sort`. That won't work (unless you use `tee`). Either separate the commands as individual commands (e.g., use `;`) or don't redirect the output to a file.

Ditto the second half, where you write the output to `sortedfield2.txt` and thus end up with nothing going to `stdout`, and nothing being piped into `uniq`.

So an alternative could be:

```
cut -f 2 practice.sam > field2.txt ; sort -o field2.txt sortedfield2.txt ; uniq -c sortedfield2.txt
```

which is the same as

```
cut -f 2 practice.sam > field2.txt 
sort -o field2.txt sortedfield2.txt 
uniq -c sortedfield2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command:

```
cut -f 2 practise.sam | uniq | sort > sorted.txt
```

In your code is wrong. The fault is "No such file or directory". Because of pipe. You can learn at this link how it is used

https://www.guru99.com/linux-pipe-grep.html